# can't resolved reference Recyclerview.adapter on androidx

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, androidx

i've migrated my project to androidx, but when i'm using androidx for recyclerview adapter the the class of `RecyclerView.Adapter` cannot be resolve

i've doing this in `gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

im using

`implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'`

Comment: How does the import of `RecyclerView.Adapter` look like?

Comment: the auto complete doesn't work so i dont know the import syntax, you may have suggestion

Comment: You'd have to `import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter`. The _Gradle_ properties should make sure to transform all dependencies. Have you tried to invalidate AS or clean your project?

Comment: i do it all, and it works, thankyou

Comment: Good to hear! Could you provide an answer or delete the question then? So everyone knows it's resolved?

Answer (score 1):

great, i use @tynn suggestion and it works,

1. i migrate to androidx
2. invalidate AS or clean my project
3. importing androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter in my adapter